# MySQL - Way to set a default return value when NULL is found?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in SQL to set a default return value when NULL is returned for part of the results?

Here is my SQL:

```
 SELECT p.id, p.title, concat( u1.meta_value, ' ', u2.meta_value ) as fullname, concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) as location 
 FROM modules_profiles p 
 LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u1 ON p.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
 LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u2 ON p.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 LEFT JOIN modules_regions r ON r.id = p.region_id
 LEFT JOIN modules_countries c ON c.id = p.country_id
 WHERE p.certification IN ( 'certified' ) AND p.country_id IN ( 2 )
 ORDER BY p.user_id ASC
```

There are times when there is no region_id set for a given profile; therefore, NULL is returned for location for that respective user_id, even though we do have a country's name (c.name).

Is there a way in this case to just return the c.name only?

Comment: coalesce and ifnull are the two functions to handle default values

Comment: did you do any research? this is a very common question with a lot of results from a simple google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` function like below, it will return the first non NULL value provided in list

```
COALESCE(col_name, 'default_value')
```

For your case, do

```
COALESCE(region_id, c.name)
```

I think, you are specifically talking about the part

```
concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) as location
```

You can modify this using `CASE` expression as well

```
case when r.name is not null and c.name is not null 
then concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) else c.name end as location
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  You've saved me a bunch of time.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You want to use MySQL's [`IFNULL(value, default)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

Comment: Well, that's certainly another way

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce could help you

```
COALESCE(region_id, 'default value')
```